# Reflection Filter types by Generic Base

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to reflect into an assembly and get out all of the types who derive from a generic type.

```
protected List<Assembly> _assemblies = new List<Assembly>(); 

public List<Type> FilterByType<T>()
{
    return this._assemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(type => typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
}
```

However when I try to call the filter method I cannot pass a Type-Less Generic

```
// This does not compile because it's an unbound generic
FilterByType<AbstractValidator<>>()
```

How can I Filter where any of my bases are a derrive from a generic?

Comment: Add a non.generic overload which accepts a Type as the parameter, then you can pass `typeof(AbstractValidator<>)`

Comment: @Gusman the rest of my logic will still work? I don't need to compare generic type definition somehow?

Comment: Look at my answer.

Comment: As a note, i am not sure if your logic will work, it will solve your problem about not using the typeless type, but to check if it derives from it is more complicated, you must check if the type is a generic definition and if it is then get the generic definition and check if it's the same (more or less resumed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeless generic types can't be used in generic functions, they can only be used to get the type.

To solve your problem create a non-generic overload accepting a Type parameter and use it:

```
protected List<Assembly> _assemblies = new List<Assembly>(); 

public List<Type> FilterByType<T>()
{
    return this._assemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(type => typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
}

public List<Type> FilterByType(Type BaseType)
{
    return this._assemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(type => BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var types = FilterByType(typeof(AbstractValidator<>));
```

Comment: Thanks let me test this out real quick

Comment: The type passes fine but it's still not filtering properly, I need to check the base types still

Answer (score 0):

I Ended up filtering them like so:

```
public static class TypeExensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypeAsEnumerable(this Type type)
    {
        for (; null != type && type != typeof(object); type = type.BaseType)
            yield return type;
    }
}

public List<Type> FilterByGenericType(Type genericType)
{
    return this._assemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        .Where(fullType => fullType.BaseTypeAsEnumerable()
                                .Where(type => type.IsGenericType)
                                .Any(baseType => baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType))
        .ToList();
}
```